# Is it possible to change a machine learning model saved as an rds file?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science

I have a machine learning model (Support Vector Machines with Polynomial Kernel) saved as an rds file and would like know if its possible to open it in R as code instead of an object, as I want modify it. (Train on a different data set which have additional inputs) Is this possible?

I understand that information about the model can be understood by doing the following and then rewritten with the same parameters but it would be much more convenient if it was possible to get the source code behind the model to then work off.

```
Model <- readRDS("model1.rds")
Summary(Model)
```

returns:

```
Length  Class   Mode 
     1   ksvm     S4
```

and

```
Model
```

returns

```
Support Vector Machines with Polynomial Kernel 

136 samples
 22 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 50 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 124, 122, 123, 123, 122, 122, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  degree  scale  C     RMSE       Rsquared    MAE      
  1       1e-03  0.25  0.9400531  0.26948023  0.7681676
  1       1e-03  0.50  0.9278696  0.27118754  0.7559654
  1       1e-03  1.00  0.9073649  0.27667363  0.7351476
  1       1e-03  2.00  0.8749052  0.29524283  0.7022990
  1       1e-03  4.00  0.8432924  0.30690580  0.6695539
  1       1e-02  0.25  0.8649211  0.29538671  0.6918704
  1       1e-02  0.50  0.8397385  0.29936839  0.6660842
  1       1e-02  1.00  0.8254333  0.30113897  0.6502524
  1       1e-02  2.00  0.8289587  0.30433998  0.6490126
  1       1e-02  4.00  0.8320745  0.31294825  0.6487897
  1       1e-01  0.25  0.8296454  0.30747527  0.6486308
  1       1e-01  0.50  0.8344243  0.31476033  0.6499654
  1       1e-01  1.00  0.8441749  0.31633515  0.6544509
  1       1e-01  2.00  0.8535258  0.31456945  0.6595723
  1       1e-01  4.00  0.8619060  0.31271215  0.6645062
  1       1e+00  0.25  0.8564814  0.31388052  0.6613590
  1       1e+00  0.50  0.8637594  0.31220123  0.6653949
  1       1e+00  1.00  0.8691346  0.31075428  0.6686576
  1       1e+00  2.00  0.8720188  0.31022913  0.6704680
  1       1e+00  4.00  0.8736167  0.31006969  0.6715086
  1       1e+01  0.25  0.8725931  0.31011668  0.6707497
  1       1e+01  0.50  0.8741016  0.30997811  0.6717619
  1       1e+01  1.00  0.8745994  0.30999984  0.6720067
  1       1e+01  2.00  0.8746420  0.31003087  0.6719952
  1       1e+01  4.00  0.8747119  0.31007240  0.6718945
  2       1e-03  0.25  0.9278514  0.27113121  0.7559409
  2       1e-03  0.50  0.9073266  0.27660246  0.7350886
  2       1e-03  1.00  0.8749297  0.29498825  0.7023035
  2       1e-03  2.00  0.8434252  0.30648759  0.6696877
  2       1e-03  4.00  0.8296849  0.29598473  0.6548526
  2       1e-02  0.25  0.8394769  0.29922811  0.6656030
  2       1e-02  0.50  0.8225812  0.30647554  0.6471741
  2       1e-02  1.00  0.8284856  0.30481597  0.6476189
  2       1e-02  2.00  0.8354892  0.30942785  0.6470264
  2       1e-02  4.00  0.8654903  0.28874153  0.6675736
  2       1e-01  0.25  0.9719262  0.18163582  0.7608615
  2       1e-01  0.50  1.0498843  0.14914096  0.8324269
  2       1e-01  1.00  1.1538404  0.12192484  0.9208610
  2       1e-01  2.00  1.2521386  0.11463212  0.9984787
  2       1e-01  4.00  1.3293049  0.10769439  1.0570698
  2       1e+00  0.25  1.3523405  0.08190648  1.0703873
  2       1e+00  0.50  1.3523405  0.08190648  1.0703873
  2       1e+00  1.00  1.3523405  0.08190648  1.0703873
  2       1e+00  2.00  1.3523405  0.08190648  1.0703873
  2       1e+00  4.00  1.3523405  0.08190648  1.0703873
  2       1e+01  0.25  1.4716348  0.06551953  1.1641090
  2       1e+01  0.50  1.4716348  0.06551953  1.1641090
  2       1e+01  1.00  1.4716348  0.06551953  1.1641090
  2       1e+01  2.00  1.4716348  0.06551953  1.1641090
  2       1e+01  4.00  1.4716348  0.06551953  1.1641090
  3       1e-03  0.25  0.9173351  0.27511200  0.7453143
  3       1e-03  0.50  0.8889770  0.28580632  0.7165424
  3       1e-03  1.00  0.8544178  0.30218510  0.6806835
  3       1e-03  2.00  0.8377603  0.29299541  0.6633006
  3       1e-03  4.00  0.8241635  0.30390397  0.6479914
  3       1e-02  0.25  0.8296864  0.29943301  0.6543154
  3       1e-02  0.50  0.8275125  0.30238935  0.6477723
  3       1e-02  1.00  0.8431461  0.29406753  0.6541412
  3       1e-02  2.00  0.8834502  0.26293743  0.6838924
  3       1e-02  4.00  0.9330564  0.22756081  0.7237417
  3       1e-01  0.25  1.0078872  0.15196775  0.7978582
  3       1e-01  0.50  1.0508254  0.13985151  0.8353149
  3       1e-01  1.00  1.0516959  0.13966326  0.8361822
  3       1e-01  2.00  1.0516959  0.13966326  0.8361822
  3       1e-01  4.00  1.0516959  0.13966326  0.8361822
  3       1e+00  0.25  0.9708866  0.16413958  0.7611715
  3       1e+00  0.50  0.9708866  0.16413958  0.7611715
  3       1e+00  1.00  0.9708866  0.16413958  0.7611715
  3       1e+00  2.00  0.9708866  0.16413958  0.7611715
  3       1e+00  4.00  0.9708866  0.16413958  0.7611715
  3       1e+01  0.25  0.9793737  0.17539453  0.7659516
  3       1e+01  0.50  0.9793737  0.17539453  0.7659516
  3       1e+01  1.00  0.9793737  0.17539453  0.7659516
  3       1e+01  2.00  0.9793737  0.17539453  0.7659516
  3       1e+01  4.00  0.9793737  0.17539453  0.7659516

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were degree = 2, scale = 0.01 and C = 0.5.
```

Comment: No, it's not possible, but the model does tell you the parameters it used with which you can fit a new model.

Comment: Thanks had the feeling that was the case